# Nginx CodeIgniter not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, configuration, nginx, php

I am new to nginx. I am transfering my server from apache to nginx but my many projects on the CodeIgniter core PHP sites working perfectly but the CodeIgniter is not work.

My sample url like this:

```
http://example.com/track/
```

this is redirect to:

```
http://example.com/track/index.php/sessions/login
```

but it returns 404 Not Found.

my server configure like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  192.168.0.80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }



    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
       deny  all;
    }
}
```

my error log file  like this

```
2013/05/15 10:21:37 [error] 2474#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.11, server: 192.168.0.80, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.80"
2013/05/15 10:21:37 [error] 2474#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.11, server: 192.168.0.80, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.0.80"
2013/05/15 10:22:05 [error] 2474#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/track/index.php/sessions/login" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 192.168.0.11, server: 192.168.0.80, request: "GET /track/index.php/sessions/login HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.80"
2013/05/15 10:26:46 [error] 2474#0: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/track/index.php/sessions/login" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 192.168.0.11, server: 192.168.0.80, request: "GET /track/index.php/sessions/login HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.80"
2013/05/15 10:28:33 [error] 2474#0: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/track/index.php/sessions/login" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 192.168.0.11, server: 192.168.0.80, request: "GET /track/index.php/sessions/login HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.80"
2013/05/15 10:29:59 [error] 2497#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/track/index.php/sessions/login" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 192.168.0.11, server: 192.168.0.80, request: "GET /track/index.php/sessions/login HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.80"
```

What's wrong? I did a search in google but not working perfectly.

Comment: Ok so a couple of fast questions,
Is this a local server?
and is this codeIgniter project running in a subfolder of your server root?, cause if it's so it kinda changes a few things

Comment: this is local-server. i am using centos for & codigniter running on the sub folder

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, should fix your rewriting issues.
If you have further questions you can ask.
[Code igniter for nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter)

Edit:
Ok so there's several ways to fix your case, but I'll describe the closest to your case

If you're going to edit in the same file as nginx conf as how I think you're doing right now then try adding this

```
location /track {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /track/index.php; 
}
```

Not sure if the routing needs `$request_uri` appended to `index.php` or not.
And i think you should configure CodeIgniter to be aware of this sub folder

```
$config['base_url'] = "192.168.0.80/track"
```

This isn't really the cleanest way to do this configuration, I'd prefer adding a domain name in the `/etc/hosts` and create a new separate server in nginx.

Comment: Replace those two lines with
`fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`
`include         fastcgi_params;`

Comment: Something goes worst when i call this URL http://192.168.0.80/track/ redirect to http://192.168.0.80 & my core PHP project not working

Comment: yea apparently you're using `fastcgi` on a port not socket, so you can keep the line with `fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;` and remove the line with `fastcgi.conf` and replace it with `include        fastcgi_params;`, I'm rewriting my answer for a more detailed version

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem earlier today: the code igniter URI routing requires that both the REQUEST_URI and the SCRIPT_NAME variables be defined. Many of the Nginx/PHP-FPM guides don't define the SCRIPT_NAME variable, so you end up with routing failures. You'll need to add a line that looks like this:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
```

and then you can use **REQUEST_URI** in your ***config.php*** file and the routing should work.